# Import this text into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, import

I have a major text file that I need to import into a database, but I honestly have no idea how to. I've tried some exploding, but I ended up dead.

The format of the file is on the bottom of this post. ID, name, members, lendable and such are column names. All information between the ---'s are part of one row. Can anybody push me towards the right direction to help me import this?

```
-------------------------------
ID: 0
Name: Dwarf remains
Members: true
Lendable: false
Stackable: false
Shop value: 0
Interface model: 2595
Model position x: -4
Model position y: 12
Model rotation x: 436
Model rotation y: 320
Model rotation z: 0
Model zoom: 1780
Interface options: [null, null, null, null, Destroy]
Ground options: [null, null, null, null, null]
Release: 27 May 2003
Quest: Dwarf Cannon
Tradeable: No
Destroy: These are the remains of the dwarf who was stationed in the Guard Tower.
Examine: The body of a Dwarf savaged by Goblins.
Weight: Unknown
-------------------------------
ID: 1
Name: Toolkit
Members: true
Lendable: false
Stackable: false
Shop value: 0
Interface model: 2679
Model position x: -3
Model position y: 2
Model rotation x: 2026
Model rotation y: 477
Model rotation z: 0
Model zoom: 1164
Interface options: [null, null, null, null, Destroy]
Ground options: [null, null, null, null, null]
Release: 27 May 2003
Quest: Dwarf Cannon
Tradeable: No
High alch: 0 coins
Low alch: 0 coins
Destroy: I got this from Captain Lawgof.
Examine: Good for repairing a broken cannon.
Weight: 0 kg
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse the document or just push all of the text into one column?

Comment: Where did this data come from? I assume its an export from somewhere, would it not be possible to go back and export the data as a more program-friendly format? like json, or xml or something!!?  And / Or how is this data currently being used? can you not take some functionality from the program currently using this data as the base for the import?!

Comment: If this is a large file, php is not the best platform for the entire job.  I just did a google search on "mysql bulk loading" and suggest you do likewise.

Comment: @ matthias, I'm posting this from work. I'll show the code I have so far when I come back home.

@ tympaniplayer, I'm trying to parse it. Each line is a new column between the ---'s.

@ RaggaMuffin, I was thinking the same, but the original author is unknown. The file was given to me and this is the only format I have.

I was personally thinking of just getting rid of the column names and new lines to have each row on a single line, and then separate the columns with a special character. That'd open a lot of doors, eventually I could open it in Excel. But there must be a better method?

Comment: @ Dan Bracuk, the file is about 40MB. Would you consider that bulk loading?

Comment: I would consider anything over 100 rows to be bulk loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, obviously you need to call the file, then you could just use plain ol' foreach and build the array. Consider this example:

```
$contents = file('file1.txt');
$data = array();
$current_key = null;
foreach($contents as $key => $value) {
    $value = explode(':', $value);
    if(count($value) > 1) {
        if($value[0] == 'ID') {
            $current_key = $value[1];
            $data[$current_key]['ID'] = trim($value[1]);
            $columns[] = 'ID'; // prepare keys for insert 
        } else {
            $data[$current_key][$value[0]] = trim($value[1]);
            $columns[] = $value[0]; // prepare keys for insert
        }
    }   
}

print_r($data);
// gather your keys for insert
$columns = array_unique($columns);
foreach($columns as $key => &$value) {
    // make the columns look like columns
    $value = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', '_', strtolower(trim($value)));
}
$columns = implode(', ', $columns);

// format values
$values = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $values .= "('" . implode("','", $value) . "'),";
}

// concatenate them (remove extra comma) 
$statement = "INSERT INTO table ($columns) VALUES " . substr($values, 0, -1);

print_r($statement);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] =>  0

            [Name] =>  Dwarf remains

            [Members] =>  true

            [Lendable] =>  false

            [Stackable] =>  false

            [Shop value] =>  0

            [Interface model] =>  2595

            [Model position x] =>  -4

            [Model position y] =>  12

            [Model rotation x] =>  436

            [Model rotation y] =>  320

            [Model rotation z] =>  0

            [Model zoom] =>  1780

            [Interface options] =>  [null, null, null, null, Destroy]

            [Ground options] =>  [null, null, null, null, null]

            [Release] =>  27 May 2003

            [Quest] =>  Dwarf Cannon

            [Tradeable] =>  No

            [Destroy] =>  These are the remains of the dwarf who was stationed in the Guard Tower.

            [Examine] =>  The body of a Dwarf savaged by Goblins.

            [Weight] =>  Unknown

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] =>  1

            [Name] =>  Toolkit

            [Members] =>  true

            [Lendable] =>  false

            [Stackable] =>  false

            [Shop value] =>  0

            [Interface model] =>  2679

            [Model position x] =>  -3

            [Model position y] =>  2

            [Model rotation x] =>  2026

            [Model rotation y] =>  477

            [Model rotation z] =>  0

            [Model zoom] =>  1164

            [Interface options] =>  [null, null, null, null, Destroy]

            [Ground options] =>  [null, null, null, null, null]

            [Release] =>  27 May 2003

            [Quest] =>  Dwarf Cannon

            [Tradeable] =>  No

            [High alch] =>  0 coins

            [Low alch] =>  0 coins

            [Destroy] =>  I got this from Captain Lawgof.

            [Examine] =>  Good for repairing a broken cannon.

            [Weight] =>  0 kg

        )

)
```

Sample Statement:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, members, lendable, stackable, shop_value, interface_model, model_position_x, model_position_y, model_rotation_x, model_rotation_y, model_rotation_z, model_zoom, interface_options, ground_options, release, quest, tradeable, destroy, examine, weight, high_alch, low_alch) VALUES ('0','Dwarf remains','true','false','false','0','2595','-4','12','436','320','0','1780','[null, null, null, null, Destroy]','[null, null, null, null, null]','27 May 2003','Dwarf Cannon','No','These are the remains of the dwarf who was stationed in the Guard Tower.','The body of a Dwarf savaged by Goblins.','Unknown'),('1','Toolkit','true','false','false','0','2679','-3','2','2026','477','0','1164','[null, null, null, null, Destroy]','[null, null, null, null, null]','27 May 2003','Dwarf Cannon','No','0 coins','0 coins','I got this from Captain Lawgof.','Good for repairing a broken cannon.','0 kg')
```

> *Important Note: You can use this as reference as I don't know what your table structure is, so the columns might be different.*

Comment: _Sidenote: Another way also is that you can format the contents of that file make format it into a csv, then `LOAD DATA LOCA INFILE` to the talbe